# Swipe Gesture Not Working in StageWebview

Tags: flex4, stagewebview

I am developing reader application in flex 4.6 and i displaying my content in StageWebView. I implemented swipe gesture in that view but its not working.

when I 'swipe' below the StageWebView, it works fine, when I 'swipe' on the StageWebView it does not recognize it.

My Code:

```
private function handleSwipe(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
trace('handleSwirpe()');
// Swipe was to the right
if (event.offsetX == 1 )
{ // or -1 for the left
webView.viewPort = null;
navigator.popView();
}
}
```

How can i do this....

Answer (score 1):

if you want to capture swipe gesture in StageWebView you should use a javascript method to detect gesture.
And this has to be coded in the page your are loading in the StageWebView space.

Hope it helps :)